# Is there a way to change the current axes object in matlab without affecting the uistack ordering?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Matlab provides a function called uistack for arranging UI objects in the depth direction (which objects are in front of which others, etc).  There is also a function (axes) for setting the current axes.  I find that when I call axes, it also automatically puts that axes object in front of all other objects (including uipanels, etc).  Is there any way to avoid this?

Here is some code that illustrates my question:

```
figure(1)
clf

ax1 = axes();
set(ax1,'position',[.1 .1 .5 .5],'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'color','r')

ax2 = axes();
set(ax2,'position',[.3 .3 .5 .5],'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'color','b')

% blue (ax2) is on top since it was created after ax1

uistack(ax1,'top')

% red (ax1) is now on top (good)

axes(ax2)

% [do some plotting or something in ax2]

% blue (ax2) is now on top (I'd rather avoid this)
```

Comment: I know I can go back and set uistack(ax1,'top') again at the end, but in my real situation I have many objects and there is one i want to keep on top regardless of what I do to any other objects (uipanels, uicontrols, etc)... its a hassle to keep having to put that object on top every time I touch any other object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `h_ax` the current axes in figure `h_fig` without putting those axes in front, use:

```
set(h_fig, 'CurrentAxes', h_ax)
```

#### Why this works

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html#description) of the `axes` function, the syntax `axes(cax)`

> makes `cax` the first object listed in the `Children` property of the figure and sets the `CurrentAxes` property of the figure to `cax`.

Making `cax` the first object listed in the `Children` property is what causes it to be in front. This can be checked by modifying that property and seeing the effect. Also, by looking at `uistack`'s code it is seen that what that function internally does it to rearrange the order of the figure's `Children`.

Setting the figure's `CurrentAxes` property to `cax` is what causes those axes to be the current ones. This can be checked by modifying that property, plotting something and seeing in what axes the plot appears.

So, setting the `CurrentAxes` property of the figure to the desired axes achieves the desired effect without moving those axes to the front.

Comment: Thanks... this is exactly what I was looking for, but I am going to edit one typo I think you made: it should be set(f, 'currentaxes',h) instead of set(h, 'currentaxes',f)

Comment: Thanks again... in retrospect this seems so obvious, so I am embarrassed to have even asked it, but I am very glad I did... in fact, it helped me figure out something else that has troubled me in the past.  Sometimes I run a long program that updates figures regularly so i can visually check some result.  Using set(0,'currentfigure',h_fig) instead of figure(h_fig) in my loop (which is analogous to what you posted, but for figures) allows me to continue editing a file, e.g., while monitoring progress in the background... :-)  Yay!

Comment: @Jed I see. That way the figure window doesn't get the focus. Nice!